# Opera off-road mode: Automatically switch on for mobile but off for wifi

Tags: opera-browser

I like Opera's off-road mode, especially the fact that I can disable loading images specifically for it, but when on WiFi, I have to manually disable it, which is an extra step.

Is it possible to set Opera to use off-road mode for mobile data, but switch it off when on WiFi?

Note: I've tagged this with Opera Mobile because only Opera Mobile and Opera Mini tags are available, but I'm talking about Opera for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no auto off-road mode in Opera.

My suggestion is that you keep both Opera for Android and Opera Mini on your device. When you're on mobile data, use Opera Mini. Else, use Opera for Android with off-road mode off.